# Is it possible to add additional application server later to single-server SharePoint 2016 installation?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016

I have installed SharePoint 2016 in single-server farm mode and I want to extend it to three-tier architecture now.

Is it possible to add another application server to the existing single-server farm that I have? or do I need to start freshly and use Multiple-Server farm option in SharePoint Products Configurations wizard during this SharePoint 2016 fresh installation?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You donot need to start from fresh. Follow these steps.

- Convert the existing server role from Single-Server to Custom / application (depending on your requirement). You can run the following powershell on the server `Set-SPServer -Identity "ServerName" -Role "new role of server`
- Now you can add more server in the farm.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed SharePoint as "Standalone Server" like described [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263202.aspx), you can't change it to a Multi Server Farm afterwards.

When you however ran a complete installation of SharePoint on a single server and you're having a separate SQL Server, you still have the option to add Servers to the SharePoint farm, by running the Configuration Wizard on the servers you want to add.